# Curl hangs when trying to do a POST on a mysql db

Tags: mysql, json, curl, http-post

I am using CURL to issue a POST request and sending a JSON to populate a mysql db. The issue it that curl hangs when I 
issue this command. If I use the RESTClient with firefox, it works perfectly and I can populate the db with the json passed. 
Its only when I am issuing the CURL that this happens.

If I remove my implementation inside the POST and just do a simple System.Out.Print, this works just fine.

Here is my curl command :

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"Time":"Dec 27, 2012 15:44:12","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe",
"totalSalary":"10000"}' http://localhost:8080/Person/people/
```

Kindly let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Is there a reason for duplicated opening curly brace?

Comment: Hi favoretti..I have got that by mistake...Kindly see the updated version..Thanks for pointing this out..

Comment: try adding -vvvvv to your curl to see if you get any more verbose output

Comment: @Bryan - here is what i got after adding the -vvvv :                C:\>curl -vvvv -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data body.json http://localhost:8080/Person/people
   Output : * About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
> POST /Person/people HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.23.1 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.23.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1
.2.5
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 9
>
* upload completely sent off: 9 out of 9 bytes
I am very new to curl, so I dont understand what it says. Kindly let me know.